# How to skip a layer for a specific recipe?

Tags: yocto

There are three layer providing same recipe.
I want to skip one of them.

$bitbake-layers show-recipes

command above shows recipes and the layers providing them,
some of them tagged (skipped), this is what I want to do.

I tried using PREFERRED_PROVIDER and PREFERRED_VERSION to the recipe I want,
did not work.
also, tried DISTRO_FEATURE_remove = "recipe i do not want", No luck!

how does that tag appear?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to skip the recipe -- this usually involves editing the recipe and I'm assuming these are third party layers.

The correct way to do this depends on your exact case (do you want the recipe from your own layer or from some third party layer to be used? are the recipe versions different?)

You can

- modify layers BBFILE_PRIORITY in the layer configuration (but this probably only makes
  sense for your own layer) to make sure one layers recipes are always
  preferred
- use PREFERRED_VERSION in your local or distro config to choose the recipe version you need
- use [BBMASK](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-BBMASK) in your local or distro config to hide actual recipe files/directories from the
  parser

> I tried using ... PREFERRED_VERSION to the recipe I want, did not work

Sorry, but that's not enough detail for anyone to help.